# Unusual Responsive Table Functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive table for a Cafe's menu. The days of the week are the headings of the columns, while the type of food are in the rows.

When the table goes into mobile view, I'm trying to get each column to appear as a separate card. Please see below for a visual example.

From this:

```
+------+---------+----------+-----------+
| -    | Monday  | Tuesday  | Wednesday |
| Soup | Tomato  |  Leek    | N/A       |
| Main | Burgers | Sausages | Pizza     |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+
```

To this:

```
+------+---------+
| -    | Monday  |
| Soup | Tomato  |
| Main | Burgers |
+------+---------+
+------+----------+
| -    | Tuesday  |
| Soup | Leek     |
| Main | Sausages |
+------+----------+
```

I've spent some time looking at various JavaScript plugins but I cannot seem to find any that provide this functionality. All of the examples I can find put the first cell of each row as the header, which is not what I want.

Can anyone help me achieve this result please.

Here is sort of what I'm looking to create although I need to have the days above each menu section

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOEeNz
*(Forked from: http://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/FCBEg)*

```css
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700";
.rwd-table {
  margin: 1em 0;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.rwd-table th {
  display: none;
}
.rwd-table td {
  display: block;
}
.rwd-table td:first-child {
  padding-top: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:last-child {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:before {
  content: attr(data-th) ": ";
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 6.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table td:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  text-align: left;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: .25em .5em;
  }
  .rwd-table th:first-child, .rwd-table td:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .rwd-table th:last-child, .rwd-table td:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

body {
  padding: 0 2em;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  color: #444;
  background: #eee;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: #34495E;
}

.rwd-table {
  background: #34495E;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: .4em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-color: #46627f;
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  margin: .5em 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    padding: 1em !important;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td:before {
  color: #dd5;
}
```

```html
<table class="rwd-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Soup">Tomato</td>
    <td data-th="Main">Burger</td>
    <td data-th="Desert">Ice Cream</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Soup">Tomato</td>
    <td data-th="Main">Burger</td>
    <td data-th="Desert">Ice Cream</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Soup">Tomato</td>
    <td data-th="Main">Burger</td>
    <td data-th="Desert">Ice Cream</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use javascript to achive this? You can also do this by only css. Also can you post a jsfiddle or give us a link so we can take it from there?

Comment: @yakutsa If achievable by CSS only then I'm more than happy to use this solution :)

Comment: Don't use table for this, you can acheive this with div and css

Answer (score 3):

Like Yakutsa said, you can do this using only css.
There are many ways to accomplish this, I will give you one though:

```css
ul { display: block; position: relative; width: 100%; }
li { display: block; position: relative; float: left; width: 15%; }

@media (min-width: 400px)
{
    ul:before { content: "- Soup Main"; display: block; position: relative; float: left; width: 15%; word-spacing: 9999999px; }
}
@media (max-width: 399px)
{
    li { width: 100%; }
    li:before { content: "- Soup Main"; display: block; position: relative; float: left; width: 50px; word-spacing: 9999999px; }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Monday<br />Tomato<br />Burgers</li>
    <li>Tuesday<br />Leek<br />Sausages</li>
    <li>Wednesday<br />N/A<br />Pizza</li>
</ul>
```